# AICc and value for k

Tags: aic

Looking for some confirmation.  We have a set of 12 soil water sensors and originally were planning on using RMSE to determine our best model of six for each sensor, but have since decided to include AICc and Nash-Sutcliffe ME to determine the best model.  We have no previous experience with AICc and are having some discussions about whether we are actually using a correct k value.  So probably simple questions - what value for k when computing AICc for this model:

Θ = 4.3 X 10-6 * ε3 - 5.5 X 10-4 * ε2 + 2.92 X 10-2 * ε -5.3 X 10-2

This is the Topp equation and relates soil water content to permittivity measurements.  Θ is water content and ε = permittivity.  Now if I take this equation and add an offset that we find between the sensor's output and an actual soil sample water content essentially providing a new model, would we add one to k? and is it appropriate to compare these two models using AICc.  Thanks for your time.

Comment: Among the numerical values you have supplied, what are the estimated parameters and what (if any) are the assumed constants?  Would this "offset" be estimated from the same data or not?  By "$k$" do you mean the number of functionally independent parameters?

Comment: The numerical values in the Topp equation were empirically derived values fitting soil water to permittivity values.  The offset value is the difference between a physically measured soil water value and output derived from the empirical Topp equation.  Yes I believe we mean number of functionally independent parameters.